# open-iscsi does not login into targets on boot

Tags: debian, iscsi, init

We have a Debian Lenny server with open-iscsi that's configured to log into a target automatically:

```
hostname:~# grep \\.startup /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf
node.startup = automatic
hostname:~# grep \\.startup /etc/iscsi/nodes/iqn..../the.correct.ip.address\,port
node.startup = automatic
node.conn[0].startup = automatic
hostname:~#
```

If I issue a restart of open-iscsi via init.d, it works fine. But if I reboot the machine, iscsi starts, but does not even search for targets. I have to manually restart it before it works.

Any ideas how to make it find the target on boot?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `/etc/network/if-up.d/open-iscsi`  script is looking for the iscsi node config files in the wrong place.

```
/etc/iscsi/nodes/*/*/default
```

vs

```
/etc/iscsi/nodes/*/*
```

or, if you have multiple interfaces configured:

```
/etc/iscsi/nodes/*/*/*
```

Edit that file accordingly and the interface should be able to be brought up on networking start.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the iSCSI service is coming up before the networking services have come online? i.e. when iSCSI loads there is no network connection for it to scan?

Comment: Nope, it starts after the network daemon. As far as I know, it *should* search for targets anyway. If it'd search, but not find anything, that's one thing, but it does not even try searching, that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a static network configuration, try change your interface declaration
(in /etc/network/interfaces) from allow-hotplug  to auto

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you mount the iscsi on boot, but if you use the fstab file, this should be your solution.

change `defautls` to `_netdev`:

```
LABEL=labelname /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

This will wait until network interfaces are up and then will look for iscsi targets to login and mount.

Thanks to ewwhite's answer on this post.

[answered on 2015](https://serverfault.com/questions/715682/correctly-mounting-san-volumes-at-boot-time)