# Correctly mounting SAN volumes at boot time

Tags: debian, boot, storage-area-network, open-iscsi

I have a system running Debian Wheezy (7.8) that connects to a storage volume exported via iSCSI using the `open-iscsi` (version 2.0) software initiator.  The iSCSI initiator correctly reconnects the volume at boot time, but it does so after the filesystems identified in `/etc/fstab` have been mounted, thus I need to manually mount the filesystem on the volume after the boot process is finished.  How do I get the system to delay mounting this filesystem until after open-iscsi has finished reconnecting the volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the network filesystems to have the `_netdev` option in `/etc/fstab`.

```
UUID=1b4fe7c0-b5fc-4b6d-9c1f /var                    ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=b6fcc760-8230-4981-99a6 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=a69a5084-247d-4b62-b835 /data                   xfs     noatime,_netdev 1 2
tmp
```

Comment: Thank you. One wonders why this option isn't mentioned in any of the documentation for the fstab file...

Comment: @Jules but it **is** mentioned in RHEL docs, here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3889